# finding peak start and end points

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a series of peaks [Peaks image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45B3G.jpg), I used matlab findpeaks to find the peak points .

I need to find peak widths and the peak start and end points ? I have started

with this code , but it is not giving me the right width calculation :

```
% If the peak is at index 150
% Scan to the right.
for k = 151:length(signal)
   if signal(k) < signal(k-1)
    % Signal is starting to fall.
    rightIndex = k-1;
    break;
  end
end
% Scan to the left.
for k = 149: -1 : 1
   if signal(k) < signal(k+1)
     % Signal is starting to fall.
     leftIndex = k+1;
     break;
  end
end
peakWidth = rightIndex - leftIndex;
```

Comment: Define "width".

Comment: the difference between the start and end of peak signal

Comment: Ok, then define "start and end" ;)

Comment: start is where the data values starts to change (fall) until it reaches the peak , and end  starting from peak the signal starts to go up until some point where the change is less . I have uploaded image of the peaks

Comment: @doe define "starts to change (fall)" and "until some point", but define them *mathematically*

Comment: What is your desired and obtained value of `peakWidth`? Have you also checked `rightIndex`and `leftIndex` separately? You can check the wrong returned indices and try to understand why you obtain that value, which may allow you to correct your algorithm. Without sample data, we are not able to check your code thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here there are two kinds of widths, on computed by `findpeaks` and one computed naively by comparing derivative to zero:

```
% generate sinal
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = x.*sin(x/5).*sin(5*x.^2);
% get derivatives
dy = diff(y);
dx = diff(x);
dy_dx = [0 dy./dx];
% plot default annotated peaks
subplot(211);
findpeaks(y,x,'Annotate','extents');
% get peaks with width computed by 'findpeaks'
[pks,locs,peakWidth1,p] = findpeaks(y,x);
subplot(212);
plot(x,y);
hold on
plot(locs,pks,'*m')
% compute starting and ending points
startpoint = zeros(size(pks));
endpoint = zeros(size(pks));
for ii = 1:length(pks)
    plot(locs(ii) + peakWidth1(ii)*[-.5 .5],pks(ii) - p(ii)/2 + [0 0],'y')
    sp = find((x < locs(ii)) & (dy_dx <= 0),1,'last');
    if isempty(sp)
        sp = 1;
    end
    startpoint(ii) = sp;
    ep = find((x > locs(ii)) & (dy_dx >= 0),1,'first') - 1;
    if isempty(ep)
        ep = length(x);
    end
    endpoint(ii) = ep;
    plot(x(startpoint(ii)),y(startpoint(ii)),'og')
    plot(x(endpoint(ii)),y(endpoint(ii)),'sr')
end
% compute second type of width using ending and starting points
peakWidth2 = x(endpoint) - x(startpoint);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @user2999345 perfect answer .                                                  why the width values for findpeaks and derivative to zero are different  ? which one is more accurate ?

Comment: just different implementations which depend on the way the "width" is defined. you define width as the x difference between "start point" and "end point" (as defined using derivatives), while `findpeaks` defines it as the signal x values difference in half prominence from the peak.

Comment: is the width at half prominence represents the peak duration time ?